# Item filtering but keeping track of filtered out items

Tags: ramda.js

Let's say I have a list of items like below and I would like to apply a list of filters onto it with ramda.

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, name: "Andreas"},
  {id: 2, name: "Antonio"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bernhard"},
  {id: 4, name: "Carlos"}
]
```

No biggie: pipe(filter(predA), filter(predB), ...)(data)

The tricky part is I would like to define my filters with a key for tracking what items have been filtered out by which filter.

```js
const filterBy = (key, pred) => subs => {
  const [res, rej] = partition(pred, subs)
  return [{[key]: rej.map(prop('id'))}, res]
}
```

This all screams monad chaining or a transducer, but I can't get my head around it how to put it all together.

Let's say I have a 2 predicates:

```js
const isEven = filterBy('id', i => i % 2 === 0)
const startsWithA = filterBy('name', startsWith('A'))
```

I would like to get a result that looks like this tuple with a rejection map and a list of "accepted" items (isEven threw out 1 and 3 and startsWithA rejected 3 and 4):

```js
[
  {
    id: [1, 3],
    name: [3, 4]
  },
  [{id: 2, name: "Antonio"}]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vanilla JS version

I'm bothered by using the field name to describe the predicate.  What happens if we also have, say, `const nameTooLong = ({name}) => name .length < 8`.  Then how could we distinguish the two predicates in the output?  So I would prefer to use descriptive predicate names, for instance,

```js
[
  {isEven: [1, 3], startsWithA: [3, 4]}, 
  [{id: 2, name: "Antonio"}]
]
```

So that's what I do in this code:

```js
const process = (preds) => (xs) => {
  const rej = Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (preds) 
    .map (([k, v]) => [k, xs .filter (x => !v (x)) .map (x => x .id)])
  )
  const excluded = Object .values (rej) .flat()
  return [rej, data .filter (({id}) => !excluded .includes (id))]
}

const data = [{id: 1, name: "Andreas"}, {id: 2, name: "Antonio"}, {id: 3, name: "Bernhard"}, {id: 4, name: "Carlos"}]

console .log (process ({
  isEven: ({id}) => id % 2 === 0, 
  startsWithA: ({name}) => name .startsWith ('A')
}) (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

It would not be overly difficult to alter this to return something like your requested format.

### Using Ramda

The question was tagged `Ramda`, and I wrote this initially using Ramda tools, with a version that looks like this:

```js
const process = (preds) => (xs) => {
  const rej = pipe (map (flip (reject) (xs)), map (pluck ('id'))) (preds)
  const excluded = uniq (flatten (values (rej)))
  return [rej, reject (pipe (prop ('id'), flip (includes) (excluded))) (data)]
}
```

And we could continue to hack away at this until we made it entirely point-free.  I just don't see any reason for that.

I'm a founder of Ramda and a big fan, but I don't see this as any more readable than the vanilla version.  There is one exception: Ramda's `map` working on a plain object is much nicer than the `Object .entries` -> `map` -> `Object .fromEntries` dance in the vanilla code.  I might use that feature and leave the rest in vanilla, though.

Comment: thank you for the elaborate answer! I like the ramda solution, even though I was secretly hoping for some sort of fantasy-land compatible type class that concatenates the tupled results, but maybe I'm just over-thinking this :-)

Comment: While we could probably use `chain` or `ap` to handle that concatenation, the position of `xs` in the definition of `rej` would likely make it difficult to go entirely point-free.  (It's possible, of course; it's always possible.  Church and Turing proved that.)  And if I'm not going entirely point-free, I see little need to try it.  But if you want to, as applied to functions, `chain (f, g) (x) //=> f (g (x)) (x)` and `ap (f, g) (x) //=> f (x) (g (x))`.  One of those will likely help, although `lift`, `converge` and `useWith` all might also work.\

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some fiddling I came up with this kind of solution. Implementing a new monad seemed unnecessary and overwriting fantasy-land/filter was also a bad idea, as my predicates are basically tagged.

[This](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?class%20Partition%20extends%20Array%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor%28items%2C%20filtered%20%3D%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super%28...items%29%0A%20%20%20%20this.filtered%20%3D%20filtered%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20filterWithKey%20%3D%20%28key%2C%20pred%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%5Bok%2C%20notOk%5D%20%3D%20partition%28pred%2C%20this.slice%28%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20const%20filtered%20%3D%20mergeDeepWith%28concat%2C%20this.filtered%2C%20%7B%5Bkey%5D%3A%20notOk%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Partition%28ok%2C%20filtered%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20filter%20%3D%20pred%20%3D%3E%20this.filterWithKey%28%22%22%2C%20pred%29%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20res%20%3D%20new%20Partition%28%5B%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%201%2C%20name%3A%20%22Andreas%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%202%2C%20name%3A%20%22Antonio%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%203%2C%20name%3A%20%22Bernhard%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bid%3A%204%2C%20name%3A%20%22Carlos%22%7D%0A%5D%29%0A%20.filterWithKey%28%27id%27%2C%20%28%7Bid%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20id%20%25%202%20%3D%3D%3D%200%29%0A%20.filterWithKey%28%27name%27%2C%20%28%7Bname%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20name.startsWith%28%27A%27%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20toIds%20%3D%20map%28prop%28%27id%27%29%29%0Aconst%20rejected%20%3D%20map%28toIds%2C%20res.filtered%29%0Aconst%20accepted%20%3D%20%5B...res%5D%0A%0Aconsole.log%28rejected%2C%20accepted%29%0A) seems to have a good mix of readability and returns basically an extended array for further processing.

```js
class Partition extends Array {
  constructor(items, filtered = {}) {
    super(...items)
    this.filtered = filtered
  }

  filterWithKey = (key, pred) => {
    const [ok, notOk] = partition(pred, this.slice())
    const filtered = mergeDeepWith(concat, this.filtered, {[key]: notOk})
    return new Partition(ok, filtered)
  }

  filter = pred => this.filterWithKey("", pred)
}

const res = new Partition([
  {id: 1, name: "Andreas"},
  {id: 2, name: "Antonio"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bernhard"},
  {id: 4, name: "Carlos"}
])
 .filterWithKey('id', ({id}) => id % 2 === 0)
 .filterWithKey('name', ({name}) => name.startsWith('A'))

const toIds = map(prop('id'))
const rejected = map(toIds, res.filtered)
const accepted = [...res]

console.log(rejected, accepted)
```

Comment: the logic here doesn't contain duplicate rejection IDs, but that is not really something I needed, so pardon that change in logic